# Multi inline column value auto add values on row

Tags: javascript, php

Here is the code for adding two txt box value into textbox3 simple js using but I need to multi inline insert perticulor column and row add automatically into total value check image here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyX1J.jpg)

like this

The price column value automatically add into show on total value how to add this code on index.php 
Please help me guys.

```
      `<html>
       <body>
       <input type="text" id="txt1"  onkeyup="sum();" />
         <input type="text" id="txt2"  onkeyup="sum();" />
         <input type="text" id="txt3" />
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function sum() {
                    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
                    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
                   var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
                    if (!isNaN(result)) {
                            document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
                                 }
                               } id="txt3" 
                                </script>
                                   </body>
                                     </html>'
```

The code for previous code into index page.

```
               <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                              <head>
                              <title>bill</title>
                                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
                       </script>


                  <br /><br />
            <div class="container">
              <body><div align="right">
                  DATE:<span id="spanDate"></span> <BR>
                    CONTACT NO: 9498815521</div>
                       <center>
            <h1>HUMMINGBIRD ACADEMY</h1>
                   <h3>PUDUKKOTTAI</h3></center><BR><BR><BR>
                             NAME&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp: JAANA &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp                       No.<input type="text" size=10 >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp                       No.<input type="text" size=10 ><br><br>
                   ADDRESS:TRICHY &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBill 
                       No.<input type="text" size=10>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp                 Bill No.<input type="text" size=10><BR><BR>
            NO.&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp: 123

               <script type="text/javascript">
                             var months = 
                 ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
                    'August','September','October','November','December'];
         var tomorrow = new Date();
            tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24));
                    document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
                                 </script> </body>



            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">
            <tr>
             <th width="30%">Item Name</th>
       <th width="10%">Item Code</th>
   <th width="45%">Description</th>
  <th width="10%">Price</th>
  <th width="5%"></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable="true" class="item_name"></td>
  <td contenteditable="true" class="item_code"></td>
  <td contenteditable="true" class="item_desc"></td>
  <td contenteditable="true" class="item_price"></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div align="right">
 <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
</div>
<div align="center">
 <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button> total<input type="text" size=10>
</div>

<br />
<div id="inserted_item_data"></div>
          </div>

               </div>
            </body>
             </html>

         <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
         var count = 1;
            $('#add').click(function(){
      count = count + 1;
     var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
          html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_name'></td>";
        html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_code'></td>";
       html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_desc'></td>";
      html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='item_price' ></td>";
            html_code += "<td><button type='button' name='remove' data- 
    row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";
     html_code += "</tr>";
   $('#crud_table').append(html_code);
        });

       $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
      var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
         $('#' + delete_row).remove();
    });

         $('#save').click(function(){
        var item_name = [];
      var item_code = [];
       var item_desc = [];
         var item_price = [];
              $('.item_name').each(function(){
            item_name.push($(this).text());
           });
          $('.item_code').each(function(){
          item_code.push($(this).text());
           });
            $('.item_desc').each(function(){
             item_desc.push($(this).text());
               });
              $('.item_price').each(function(){
              item_price.push($(this).text());
               });
              $.ajax({
                    url:"insert.php",
                    method:"POST",
                     data:{item_name:item_name, item_code:item_code, 
                           item_desc:item_desc, item_price:item_price},
                  success:function(data){
                                        alert(data);
                                         $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
                                 for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
                                   {
                             $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
                                   }
                              fetch_item_data();
                                        }
                                  });
                                 });


                       fetch_item_data();

                         });

               </script>
```